# How to Trigger event to change value in Input Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am attempting to learn HTML and Javascript, and with this, I am working on building a simple calculator device, where all of the numbers and operators are buttons that are clicked, and the results are displayed in an input box. However I have had issues with, when clicking on the buttons, having the events trigger to display the selected numbers value in the box.

Here is my HTML and JS:

```js
var numString = "";

$('.number').click(function() {  
  numString += $(this).val().toString;
  $('input[name=display]').val(numString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="display" name="display" disabled></input>
<button id="button1" class="number" value="1">1</button>
```

Comment: You have to clear inside click function like numString = "" else it will add whenever you click button

Comment: The `toString` should be `toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below code . it should be `.toString()` instead of `.toString`

```js
var numString = "";
$('.number').click(function() {
     numString += $(this).val().toString();
     $('input[name=display]').val(numString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="display" name="display" disabled></input>

<button id="button1" class="number" value="1">1</button>
```

Comment: @Professor_Joykill did you try running the snippet above?

Answer (score 1):

You have a type in `$(this).val().toString`
`toString` is a function, I believe the intention was to call it like this `$(this).val().toString()`

After fixing toString, your code would produce 1 -> 11 -> 111...